# valor nulo al enviar un dato de angular a spring

Tags: angular, spring-boot, null

Necesito que el usuario seleccione una estacion y que se filtren los datos mostrandolos es una grafica. La consulta en spring se encuenra bien haciendo las pruebas con postman funciona bien. Pero no se como capturarel dato que selecciona el usuario en Angular  se envia valor nulo.

HTML.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="dato" (change)="filtro()">
  <option value="0">seleccione una opcion</option>
  <option value="bomberos">bomberos</option>
  <option value="hospital">hospital</option>
</select>
```

COMPONENT.

```
filtro(){
  let x : String = '';
  x = this.dato;
  this._dato.filtEstacion(x);
  console.log("----------------"+x);
}
```

service

```
  filtEstacion(estacion : any):Observable<any>{
    let val = this.getGraficapm10();
    let pm10 = val.pipe(filter(x => x == estacion));
    console.log(pm10);
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/variables/pm10/consulta`,pm10);
  }
```

Spring controller

```
  filtEstacion(estacion : any):Observable<any>{
    let val = this.getGraficapm10();
    let pm10 = val.pipe(filter(x => pm10.estacion == estacion));
    console.log(pm10);
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/variables/pm10/consulta`,pm10);
  }
```

DAO

```
@Query("select dato_estandar, fecha_hora_inicio from pm10 where estacion= ':estacion' ALLOW FILTERING") 
public List<pm10> estacion(@Param("estacion") String estacion);
```

Comment: como esta tu controlador en back? estas haciendo una peticion get la cual no envia body, necesitas cambiarla de get a post o en el get enviar como parametro de la url la estacion

Comment: Ya lo intente cambiar post pero el valor sigue siendo nullo. Recibo el parámetro para enviar el dato a la interface DAO